# How to connect a mesh vertex groups with an armature bones

Tags: armature, bones, vertex-groups, weight-painting

I have this mesh and armature found in this [blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1v4hopkgethsq5x/test%20%281%29.blend?dl=0). What I want to do is to connect the bones with the created vertex groups. And I don't want to use automatic weighting option as this will create different and new vertex groups. I want to use the vertex groups I manually created in the attached blend file.
Please if anyone could please advise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rename the vertex groups so they have the same name as the bone you want to deform them. Add the *Armature* modifier. Make sure *Vertex Groups* is checked (it is by default) and you are done.

Comment: this is not working I do this but still the armature and the mesh are not connected to each other

Comment: Have you referenced the armature object in the modifier? What about the vertex weights?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but I just had a similar problem, and I'm sure others will too. My armature just stopped working. Below, is the solution I found (while checking through advice from early comments in this thread, Thanks!). Somehow I had unchecked this box:[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a better way (and I usually create the groups after parenting) is to parent the bones with automatic weights, then go into edit mode, select a vertex groups vertices, then go to the corresponding bone and assign those vertices (removing any that were in the bone group previously). Or you could remove the automatic bone groups and rename your own vertex groups Bone, Bone.001, Bone.002, and so on. Or, you could parent the bones with empty groups and then copy from one group to another.

I'm sure there's a setting, however, in the mess of buttons and sliders that changes the bone groups.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had an armature that was already attached to several mesh parts, weight painting completed and all working correctly. I realized I needed to add some new bones for an eye controller and I wasn't sure how to do this without mucking up all of the carefully painted vertex groups. The specific question is:

How do I add a new bone and assign a new vertex group to that bone, without any automatic weight painting or re-parenting?

Turns out it's very easy.

Make the bone. Name the bone. Go to the mesh that needs to be deformed by it. Make sure that you have an *Armature* modifier on the mesh, and that the *Bind To Vertex Groups* option is turned on in the modifier, and that you have assigned the correct armature in the modifier. In the object data section, create a new *Vertex Group* and name it the exact same name as your new bone.

This works for me. Unfortunately, you will likely need to do manual weight painting of the mesh. But if the mesh is isolated from the rest of the model you can just pair it to the armature after creating the new bone, and choose to paint weights automatically. This will include influences from all other bones though, so you have to decide which is easier to deal with.